# Woocommerce API Post method not working with HTTP request Via POSTMAN - Getting Invalid signature

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Woocommerce API Version - /wc/v3/

**Get method is working fine** - to get all product list but **when i try post method** with add product its not working

I am getting below error message

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
    "message": "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

below is more details

```
 URL - http://*********/wp-json/wc/v3/products& tried without & as well 
    
    Auth type - Oath 1.0 
    
    Signature Method - HMAC-SHA1 & also tried sha256 
    Consumer Key ***
    Consumer Secret  ***
    Timestamp - echo timestamp in wordpress and put same here 
    Nonce-  Random number 
    Version - 1.0
```

Realm, verifier, Callback URL not sure what to put as i am trying same in POSTMAN

Check screenshot here - https://snipboard.io/6pkxTU.jpg

I have also tried some .htaccess update method from stackoverflow other query but its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure you have valid API-keys.And Try with Basic Authentication.
Username:Consumer_Key
Password:Consumer_Secret

Comment: What i mentioned. I already have used valid key - that's why its working with get method..!! same key not working for post method - i have given full read and write access to that key user

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as well , and after searching with the `check_oauth_signature` in `class-wc-rest-authentication.php` that the problem is `hash_equals( $signature, $consumer_signature )` return false. So I go through the whole variable related with $sinatue then something wired thing.

`$string_to_sign = $http_method . '&' . $base_request_uri . '&' . $query_string;`

`$query_string` would come with the header but if you set the `Body` into `form-data` on Postman that form-data would be coming with header(aww.. really ridiculous, rid off that). In my scenario, click the raw and JSON instead for form-data, the hash issue would strike.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the Postman, click in Params, create two Keys called "consumer_key" and "consumer_secret" and fills the values with API Keys (consumer key and consume secret generated into woocomerce). In Authorization tab do not fill anything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).